# displaying "no results found " on the same JSP page gives error using JAVA struts2 and array list

Tags: javascript, jsp, jdbc, arraylist, struts2

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Donor Logged in !</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
h1 {
    color: black;
    background-color: black;
    font: bold;
    outline-color: gray;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-family: cursive;
}

h3 {
    color: silver;
    background-color: windowframe;
}

h4 {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}

.loginDialoge {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.loginDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.loginDialog>div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.loginDialoge>div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 2px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
    background: #00d9ff;
}

form p {
    text-align: center;
}

form p input {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 28px;
}

.loginDialog:target {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#login">Last Donated Date</a></li>
                    <li><a href="DonorUpdateProfile.jsp">Edit Profile </a></li>
                    <li><a href="logout2">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>


        <div align="center">

    Welcome, <s:property value="#session.name"/>
            <h3>Search based on blood banks !</h3>

            <h4>Select Blood Group</h4>
            <s:form action="SearchOneAction">
                <select name="searchone.blood">
                    <option value="opositive">O+</option>
                    <option value="onegative">O-</option>
                    <option value="apositive">A+</option>
                    <option value="anegative">A-</option>
                    <option value="bpositive">B+</option>
                    <option value="bnegative">B-</option>
                    <option value="abpositive">AB+</option>
                    <option value="abnegative">AB-</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <s:textfield placeholder="Enter STD code" name="searchone.std" />
                <s:submit value="Search" />
            </s:form>
            <s:if  test="%{result.size>0}">
            <table border="2">
                <th>
                <tr>
                    <td>BloodbankName</td>
                    <td>city</td>
                    <td>address</td>
                    <td>Contact</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>A+</td>
                    <td>A-</td>
                    <td>B+</td>
                    <td>B-</td>
                    <td>AB+</td>
                    <td>AB-</td>
                    <td>O+</td>
                    <td>O-</td>
                </tr>
                </th>
                <s:iterator value="result">
                    <s:iterator>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="address" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="city" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="contact" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="email" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="opositive" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="onegative" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="apositive" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="anegative" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="bpositive" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="bnegative" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="abpositive" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="abnegative" /></td>

                        </tr>
                    </s:iterator>

                </s:iterator>
            </table>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
            <div>No Records Found !</div>
            </s:else>
            <h3>Search based on Donors !</h3>
            <s:form action="SearchTwoAction">
                <s:textfield placeholder="Enter STD code" name="searchtwo.std" />
                <s:textfield placeholder="Enter Blood Group" name="searchtwo.bg" />
                <s:submit value="Search" />
            </s:form>
            <s:if  test="%{resulttwo.size>0}">
            <table border="2">
                <th>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donor Name</td>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>Contact</td>
                </tr>
                </th>
                <s:iterator value="resulttwo">
                    <s:iterator>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="address" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="city" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="age" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="contact" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </s:iterator>
                </s:iterator>
            </table>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
            <div>No Records Found !</div>
            </s:else>
            <h3>Search based on Last Donated Date : </h3>
            <s:form action="SearchThreeAction">
            <s:textfield placeholder="STD code" name="searchthree.std"/>
            <s:textfield placeholder="Blood Group" name="searchthree.bg"/>
            <s:submit value="Search"/>
            </s:form>
            <s:if test="%{resultthree.size>0}">
            <table border="2">
                <th>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donor Name</td>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>Contact</td>
                    <td>Last Donated Date</td>
                </tr>
                </th>
                <s:iterator value="resultthree">
                    <s:iterator>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="address" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="city" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="age" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="contact" /></td>
                            <td><s:property value="last" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </s:iterator>
                </s:iterator>
            </table>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
            <div>No Records Found !</div>
            </s:else>
        </div>
        <div id="login" class="loginDialog">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="close">X</a>
            <h2>Last Donated Date !</h2>
            <form action="LastDonatedDateAction" method="post">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="donated.name" placeholder="Username">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="donated.last" placeholder="Last Donated Date(YYYY-MM-DD)" size="30">
                </p>
                <p class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I have posted jsp page in which I have used strut's if and else tag to display results.  If no results are found it should display "no results/records found".
It works perfectly when I redirect it to another JSP page on button click but what should be done if i want to display it on same JSP page on button click?
I am using arraylist to fetch results.  Its already showing "no records found".  But I want to hide it initially so what should be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display "no result found" using arraylist in struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279378/how-to-display-no-result-found-using-arraylist-in-struts2)

Comment: put the message in one div and style it as display none (style="display:none;"). Then we will hide it. Later show it using jquery show().

Comment: @RomanC sir previous question was mine only which you have suggested me..I asked for changes but they forced me to put a new question so can you help me sir ? :)

Comment: @Satya sir how can i be able to do that ? can you provide me with code if possible because I am not familiar with jquery :(

Comment: But i can be able to use div tag for else condition because i am using struts's if and else tag ?